# Cross Validate an rpart() model using the caret package error: Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret, rpart

**Problem**

I have a data frame called **FID** (see below) and I am attempting to build and **cross-validate an rpart() model** following this [tutorial](http://https:/https://discuss.datasciencedojo.com/t/how-can-i-perform-cross-validation-using-rpart-package-on-titanic-dataset/138). I have successfully produced the code correctly until I reach the section that trains the model. When I run the model, I am getting this **error message** (below):

**Error Message**

> Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

I have read a few [questions](http://https:/https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-fix-the-problem-of-error-in-xj-i-invalid-subscript-type-list/16627), articles, and, Stack Overflow pages regarding the caret train application and about this error message, but I do not understand the issue. I am not an advanced R user and I have tried to write this code using different syntaxes

If anyone is able to help with this issue, I would be deeply appreciative.

Thank you in advance

**R-Code:**

```
  library(caret)

# Step 1: Get row numbers for the training data
trainRowNumbers <- createDataPartition(Rpart.Cross.Validate.Caret$FID, p=0.8, list=FALSE)

# Step 2: Create the training  dataset
trainData <- Rpart.Cross.Validate.Caret[trainRowNumbers,]

# Step 3: Create the test dataset
testData <- Rpart.Cross.Validate.Caret[-trainRowNumbers,]

# Subset the features we want to use
features <- dplyr::select(trainData, Year, Month)
head(features)

##Structure of features
  'data.frame': 736 obs. of  2 variables:
  $ Year : num  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
  $ Month: Factor w/ 12 levels "January","February",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

# Set up caret to perform 10-fold cross validation repeated 3 times
caret.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 10,
                              repeats = 3)

# Use caret to train the rpart decision tree using 10-fold cross 
# validation repeated 3 times and use 15 values for tuning the
# cp parameter for rpart. This code returns the best model trained
# on all the data! Mighty!
rpart.cv <- train(FID ~ ., 
                  data = trainData[, features],
                  method = "rpart",
                  trControl = caret.control,
                  tuneLength = 15)

##Model predictions
Fitted_model<-predict(rpart.cv)
```

**Data frame: FID**

```
structure(list(FID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 144, 145, 146, 
147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 
160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 
173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 
186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 
199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 
212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 
225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 
238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 
251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 
264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 
277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 
290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 
303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 
316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 
329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 
342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 
355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 
368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 
381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 
394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 
407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 
420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 
433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 
446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 
459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 
472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 
485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 
498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 
511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 
524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 
537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 
550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 
563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 
576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 
589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 
602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 
615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 
628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 
641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 
654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 
667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 
680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 
693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 
706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 
719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 
732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 
745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 
758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 
771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 
784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 
797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 
810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 
823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 
836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 
849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 
862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 
875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 
888, 889, 890, 891, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 
901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 
914, 915, 916, 917, 918), Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), 
    Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L
    ), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
    "December"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 917L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why are you using `data = trainData[, features]` within `train`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete

```
# Subset the features we want to use
features <- dplyr::select(trainData, Year, Month)
head(features)
```

and replace `data = trainData[, features]` with `data = trainData`, your code runs fine.
Simply use

```
rpart.cv <- train(FID ~ ., 
                  data = trainData,
                  method = "rpart",
                  trControl = caret.control,
                  tuneLength = 15)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to make this work all morning and the solution was that simple. Slap of the forehead moment. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you out!